# Java inside Javascript - Pass an Array / column Values to a Hashmap

Tags: javascript, java, abap

Hello Javascript Experts,

I have a requirement where I have to pass some values to a SAP Function Module using JavaScript.

Please see attached snapshot for input parameters in SAP where I need to pass values using javaScript:

[image: ABAP function module parameters SE37]

I need to pass values (highlighted yellow in snapshot)

```
Row
IT_VALUES
Column         APPLID  | FILEDNAME |  F  |  LOW
                       |           |     |
Values         LO_SRS  | PLANT     |  V  |  4060

Row             Values
ID_DIALOGID     DIA_LO_SRS
ID_PERSKEYTP    U
ID_PERSKEY      USERID
ID_ORIGIN       A
```

I was able to pass row values for `ID_DIALOG`, `ID_PERSKEY`, `ID_PERSKEYTYP`, `ID_ORIGIN` without any issue (see code below).

```
Row             Values
ID_DIALOGID     DIA_LO_SRS
ID_PERSKEYTP    U
ID_PERSKEY      USERID
ID_ORIGIN       A
```

--JavaScript--

```
// Main function: ztest    
function ztest(Par){    
   importClass(java.util.HashMap); 
    var inputParams = new HashMap();
    inputParams.put("ID_DIALOG", 'DIA_LO_SRS');
    inputParams.put("ID_PERSKEYTYP", 'U');
    inputParams.put("ID_PERSKEY", 'USERID');
    inputParams.put("ID_ORIGIN", 'A' );
    return inputParams;
}
```

But input field `IT_VALUES` is an internal table in SAP and have got 4 columns

```
Row
IT_VALUES
Column        APPLID  | FILEDNAME |  F  |  LOW
```

I have to pass below column values in IT_VALUES

```
Row
IT_VALUES
Column         APPLID  | FILEDNAME |  F  |  LOW
                       |           |     |
Values         LO_SRS  | PLANT     |  V  |  4060
```

I think i can use an array

```
var arr = {
             IT_VALUES : 
               [
                 {
                   APPLID        : "LO_SRS",
                   FEILDNAME     : "PLANT",
                   F             : "V",
                   LOW           : "4060"
                 }
               ]
           }
```

or Object

```
var arr = function() 
{
   return {APPLID: 'LO_SRS', FIELDNAME: 'PLANT', F: 'V', LOW : '4060'}
}

var it_values = arr();
```

but i don't know how to pass column values values to a hashmap.

```
    var inputParams = new HashMap();
    inputParams.put("IT_VALUES",????????????????????????????????????)
    inputParams.put("ID_DIALOG", 'DIA_LO_SRS');
    inputParams.put("ID_PERSKEYTYP", 'U');
    inputParams.put("ID_PERSKEY", 'USERID');
    inputParams.put("ID_ORIGIN", 'A' );
    return inputParams;
}

var bapiRet = mConnection.runFunction("FPB_PERS_POST_FOR_DIALOG", inputParams);
```

Please help.. :)

Comment: 1) Your JavaScript structure is a little unorthodox.. certainly not DRY 2) where did `java.util.HashMap` come from?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to know how to assign an object to a key in another object. To clarify, your `arr` function is returning an object, not an array.

```
var arr = function() {
  // - this is called an object
  return {
    APPLID: 'LO_SRS',
    FIELDNAME: 'PLANT',
    F: 'V',
    LOW : '4060',
  };
};
```

you can just pass it along to any other object like the `inputParams`, and there's no `HashMap` in javascript, just use another object:

```
var inputParams = {};
inputParams["IT_VALUES"] = it_values;
inputParams["ID_DIALOG"] = 'DIA_LO_SRS';
// etc...
return inputParams;
```

or you can do this:

```
var inputParams = {
  IT_VALUES: it_values,
  ID_DIALOG: 'DIA_LO_SRS',
  // etc...
};

return inputParams;
```

hope that helps

Comment: Thank you Dux. 

I have tried your suggestion but when i pass inputParams to SAP function .runFunction,  I am getting error :

Cannot convert [object Object] to java.util.Map  :(